# Sending a welcome letter email next to the normal invoice email

Tags: email, invoice

After a customer has purchased a product from our Magento shop, he receives the invoice via email. That is working well.

Now I want to send another email, a "welcome letter", to the same email address if the customer has purchased a product of a certain category.

My question: Is there a built-in way (i.e. without PHP coding) to achieve that, tied to a product category or alike?

If not, what would be the easiest way to achieve that via PHP coding?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do that.

What needs to be done to achieve this goal is:

1. Create a new Module your use a base module which you already created for the shop
2. Create an observer that listens to the 'sales_order_place_after' event

From there you can retrieve the order and order items (and products) and check if you need to send an e-mail.